# Agregar clase a una columna sin afectar el header [DataTables.net]

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

Intento añadir una clase a una columna sin tener que afectar el `header` pero, no he podido lograrlo, he intentado varias cosas como.

Esto lo dice la [API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow)

```
"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
    if ( data[5] == "1" ) {
        $(row).addClass('badge badge-success');
}}
```

Esta segunda es la que estoy usando y afecta a toda la columna pero solo quiero que afecte a los `td`:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
       targets: 5,
       className: 'badge badge-success',
    }
],
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabajar solo con las celda de datos utiliza la función de [createdCell();](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) Donde esta te permite manipular desde el tag de td.

```
columnDefs: [ {
    targets: 5,
    createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
       if ( cellData < 1 )
        $(td).addClass('badge badge-success');
    }
  } ]
```

Para no afectar el header, cellData  es el indice de cuando renderiza; escapalo.

Comment: Está información ah servido, me quedo con la que comentaste antes de editar.

Comment: Va, entonces la regreso

Comment: Pude probar gracias a esto, otra opción, no se si sea buena práctica pero me sirvio.

`{data: 'status', orderable: false, 
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                            if ( data == 1 ) {
                                return '<span class="badge badge-success">'+data+'</span>'
                            } else {
                                return '<span class="badge badge-danger">'+data+'</span>'
       }
   }
},`

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo con `rowCallback` asi:

```js
$("#table").DataTable({
  'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
    console.log(data[4]);
    if(data[4] == "1"){
      $(row).find('td:eq(4)').addClass('badge badge-success');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.badge {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Lo he intentado también en otra oportunidad pero, tampoco funciona, no añade nada.

Comment: A mi si me funciona, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo que tengo mal entonces.
Esté es mi código:
https://js.do/code/252401

Comment: Si pones el `console.log` puedes ver los datos?

Comment: Me dice que es `undefined`

Comment: Otra opcion puede ser usar `columnDefs` y remover la clase de los `th` con jQuery.

Comment: Lo he hecho como dices pero aún tengo algunos problemas de diseño, gracias.

Comment: @J.Zambrano creo que es porque le falta agregar la referencia a JQuery. Yo uso [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Ya pude solucionar con el comentario de @Aaron. Gracias por ayudar colegas. :)

Answer (score -1):

SI SE TRABAJA CON DATOS CARGADOS DESPUES (como puede ser base de datos) la funcion se trabaja asi; por ejemplo en mi caso:

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
                if ( $('td:eq(5)', row).text() == "devolviendo") {
                  $('td:eq(5 )', row).addClass( 'clase_1' );
                }else if ( $('td:eq(5)', row).text() == "libre") {
                    $('td:eq(5 )', row).addClass( 'clase_2' );
                }
              }
```

---